# Creating a C# NuGet Package with Static Files and Accessing Them

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently developing a C# project (.net 7) and facing the need to create a NuGet package containing static files, specifically a .venv folder containing some Python code. The goal is to have these static files accessible after installing the package in another project. Could someone guide me through the process of creating such a package and ensuring the static files are readily accessible in the consuming project? I'm eager to learn about any step-by-step guides or best practices to achieve this. Your assistance would be highly valued. Thank you in advance for your help!

I've explored various approaches, including attempting to add the setting below to the each file on the .csproj:

```
<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
<CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044241/why-are-files-in-nuget-content-folder-not-copied-to-output-directory#77045771 this existing answer may help.  TLDR; make a nuspec and package content explicitly.

Comment: Question is already answered on SO.